# Split an single-use large IEnumerable<T> in half using a condition

Tags: c#, xml, performance, linq, bigdata

Let's say we have a `Foo` class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }

    // some other properties

    public static Foo CreateFromXml(Stream str)
    {
        Foo f = new Foo();

        // do the parsing

        return f;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Foo> GetAllTheFoos(DirectoryInfo dir)
    {
        foreach(FileInfo fi in dir.EnumerateFiles("foo*.xml", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
        {
            using(FileStream fs = fi.OpenRead())
                yield return Foo.CreateFromXML(fs);
        }
    }
}
```

For you to gain perspective, I can say that data in these files has been recorded for about 2 years at frequency of usually several Foo's every minute.

Now: we have a parameter called `TimeSpan TrainingPeriod` which is about 15 days for example. What I'd like to accomplish is to call:

```
var allTheData = GetAllTheFoos(myDirectory);
```

and obtain `IEnumerable<Foo> TrainingSet, TestSet` of it, where `TrainingSet` consists of the `Foos` from the first 15 days of recording, and the `TestSet` of all the rest. Then, out of the `TrainingSet` we want to calculate some constant-memory data (like average `Value`, some linear regression etc.), and then start consuming the TestSet, using the calculated values. In other words, my code should **semantically** be equvalent to:

```
TimeSpan TrainingPeriod = new TimeSpan(15, 0, 0); // hope it says 15 days

var allTheData = GetAllTheFoos(myDirectory);
List<Foo> allTheDataList = allTheData.ToList();

var threshold = allTheDataList[0].Timestamp + TrainingPeriod;

List<Foo> TrainingSet = allTheDataList.Where(foo => foo.Timestamp < threshold).ToList();
List<Foo> TestSet = allTheDataList.Where(foo => foo.Timestamp >= threshold).ToList();
```

By the way the XML file naming convention ensures me, that Foos will be returned in chronological order.
Of course, I do not want to store it all in memory, which happens every time `.ToList()` is called. So I came up with another *solution*:

```
TimeSpan TrainingPeriod = new TimeSpan(15, 0, 0);

var allTheData = GetAllTheFoos(myDirectory);

var threshold = allTheDataList.First().Timestamp + TrainingPeriod; // a minor issue

var grouped = from foo in allTheData
              group foo by foo.Timestamp < Training;

var TrainingSet = grouped.First(g => g.Key);
var TestSet = grouped.First(g => !g.Key); // the major one
```

However, there is a minor and a major issue about that piece of code. The minor one is that the first file is read twice at least - doesn't matter actually. But it looks like TrainingSet and TestSet access the directory independently, read every file twice and select only those holding a particular timestamp constraint. I'm not too puzzled by that - in fact if it worked I would be puzzled and would have to rethink LINQ once again. But this raises file-access issues, and every file is parsed two times, which is a total waste of CPU time.

So my question is: can I achieve this effect using only simple LINQ/C# tools? I think I can do this in a good ol' brute-force way, overriding some `GetEnumerator()`, `MoveNext()` methods and so on - please don't bother typing it, I can totally handle this on my own.

However, if there is some elegant, short&sweet solution to this, it would be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

**Another edit:**

The code I finally came up is the following:

```
public static void Handle(DirectoryInfo dir)
{
    var allTheData = Foo.GetAllTheFoos(dir);

    var it = allTheData.GetEnumerator();

    it.MoveNext();

    TimeSpan trainingRange = new TimeSpan(15, 0, 0, 0);

    DateTime threshold = it.Current.Timestamp + trainingRange;

    double sum = 0.0;
    int count = 0;

    while(it.Current.Timestamp <= threshold)
    {
        sum += it.Current.Value;
        count++;

        it.MoveNext();
    }

    double avg = sum / (double)count;

    // now I can continue on with the 'it' IEnumerator
}
```

Of course still some minor issues are present i.e. veryfying the output of MoveNext() (is it end of the IEnumerable already?), but the general idea is clear I hope. **BUT** in the real code it's not just average I'm calculating, but different kinds of regression etc. So I'd like to somehow extract the first part, pass it as an IEnumerable to a class deriving from my

```
public abstract class AbstractAverageCounter
{
    public abstract void Accept(IEnumerable<Foo> theData);
    public AverageCounterResult Result { get; protected set; }
}
```

to separate responsibilities for extraction of training data and it's processing. Plus after the process depicted before I get an `IEnumerator<Foo>`, but I think an `IEnumerable<Foo>` would be preferred to pass it to my `TheRestOfTheDataHandler` instance.

Comment: How would you expect to process these, if you don't have them all in memory? You can't expect to skip between the two groups *and* only stream it once. Are your values all in chronological order? It's not really clear what kind of answer you're looking for.

Comment: @JonSkeet couldn't he just create two custom IEnumerables (backed by single source IEnumerable)? That way he *would* divide the set properly and stream once

Comment: I think MoreLinq's [Split](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Split.cs) would help here. I think the OP wants to avoid creating the intermediate lists in memory and just pull the results one by one

Comment: Something like `let IsTraining = foo.Timestamp < Training`/`select new { IsTraining, foo }`? If you want one enumeration but two result sets (effectively), you will have to add extra data to the result, if only to split it at the end. And, as Jon said, you can't stream both results independently without at least *some* buffering.

Comment: @joozek: But if you want to look at the first value from set X when everything in the stream so far is in set Y, you either need to buffer everything from Y or discard it. It's unclear what the OP needs to do here.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah, I see now. I'd probably create function like `Task TheFunction(IEnumerable<Foo>, Predicate<Foo>, Func<Foo, Task> onTrue, Func<Foo, Task> onFalse)` to execute and collect all the tasks

Comment: Actually when I look now, the primary question might be totally confusing, so I think I should introduce more details here. Let's say every `Foo` instance has a `double Value` property. Out of the training set we want to calculate the average `Value` in those 15 first days (which can of course be performed without storing them all in memory) and then somehow use the average when enumerating the `TestSet`. In other word, in this use case the first IEnumerable will be consumed before we even touch the second one. **I WILL EDIT THE ORIGINAL QUESTION**

Comment: You are making a very drastic mistake by assuming you'll iterate files in chronological order.  That is *not* how the file system works.  Disaster will strike when files get deleted or restored from backup.  Guaranteed to happen some rainy day.  There are no practical cures for having hundreds of thousands of files on a disk, only a database will get you somewhere.

Comment: @Hans Passant - thanks for this one. Actually now I see that I've kinda overlook the ordering issue (or believe it would _magically_ somehow work itself out), which is a really significant mistake on my side.

Comment: var it = allTheData.GetEnumerator(); should be used in a `using` clause, i guess it could leak an IO handle otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to imlement a stateful iterator pattern over the ienumerator obtained from the initial ienumerable.

```
IEnumerable<T> StatefulTake(IEnumerator<T> source, Func<bool> getDone, Action setDone);
```

This method just checks done, calls MoveNext, yields Current and updates done if movenext returned false.

Then you split your set with subsequent calls to this method and doing partial enumeratiin on that with following methods for example:
TakeWhile
Any
First
...
Then you can do any operations on top of that, but each of those must be enumerated to the end.

```
var source = GetThemAll();
using (var e = source.GetEnumerator()){
 bool done=!source.MoveNext();
 foreach(var i in StatefulTake(e, ()=>done,()=>done=true).TakeWhile(i=>i.Time<...)){
  //...
 }

 var theRestAverage = StatefulTake(e,()=>done,()=>done=true).Avg(i=>i.Score);
 //...
}
```

Its a pattern i use often in my async toolkit.

Update: fixed the signature of the StatefulTake method, it can not use a ref parameter. Also the initial call to MoveNext is necessary. The three kinds of `done` varable referencess and the method itself should be encapsulated in a context class.

Comment: Sorry for formatting. Posted from a tiny android screen.